# Scrape data from ajax

Tags: javascript, excel, ajax, vba

I'm trying to scrape from https://www.goaloong.net/

This my first goal:

[image]

I need to have all the live events, excluded next and finished matches.

My difficulty is to extract only the data I need and find the live event time.
I need this data:
ID-START TIME-LEAGUE-HOME-AWAY-SCORE-TIME

This data are here https://www.goaloong.net/gf/data/bf_us.js.

Can you offer me some help please?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Added vba code

```
Sub get_test()

Dim objHTML As HTMLDocument
Dim objElement As Object
Set objHTML = New HTMLDocument
    Url = "https://www.goaloong.net/gf/data/bf_us.js"
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", Url, False
    .Send
    objHTML.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
End With

a = objHTML.body.innerHTML
   
Row = Split(a, ";")

leng = UBound(Row) - LBound(Row)
For n = 2 To leng
Cells(n, 1) = Row(n)
Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: You analyze the page and write the javascript needed to extract the data you want. Like document.getElementsByClassName('theClass')[0];

Comment: Hi, could you make me understand? The analysis is this:
var A=Array(431);
var B=Array(156);
var C=Array(72);
var matchcount=430;
var sclasscount=155;
A[1]=[1986533,112,4522,40786,'Tanta','Al Zarka','2021-03-07 12:55:00','2021-03-07 14:08:55',3,2,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,'','',,'',0.25,'',70,'',,'True',6,5,1,,'','','',0];
 etc etc

Comment: I added the code, I have difficulty extracting the data and I can't find the minutes.

Comment: I suggest you split this question into two. Question 1: First ask about how to get all the live matches off the first url. When you say all do you mean all matches on that page? Or just those in results section? Or just English League? etc   Question 2: Then you ask a follow-up question at a later date about the content of team table other. When you come to team table other question specify which table? Just the first? For the match you show above I see 4 tables that match team table other. I suggest that when you ask question 1 you add end column to output table requiring the match url

Comment: This is because this will be needed for question 2 so might as well have it ready upfront. Just a thought. Also, think about how the combined results will be displayed. Will each match have its own worksheet? Should it be the row you show for a match followed by the team table other(s) for that match then a blank line, then repeat for all the other results? Finally, provide a little more detail about  isn't working with your code. For example, which items can't you extract e.g. the minutes. That info should be in your question.

Comment: Ok, I must update this discussion or I've to start new discussion? I wrote "I need to have all the live events".

Comment: This is only my opinion. I would  keep a copy of this question text on my desktop and split that in two. The first question would be what I [edit] this one to deal with. Wait until you have some answers. Review those. Try again to answer question 2 and if you then still can't solve part two, come back and post question 2 (using some of the text you saved earlier to desktop) as a new question.

Comment: Forgive my football ignorance. So all live events is currently from FC Koln v Werder Bremen at top to Birmingham v Arsenal at bottom? Does all live events exclude results section? I have no knowledge of this.

Comment: Yes, all live events are the started events, excluded future events and results. In this page there are too many data, I need few things. The events of the single day would also be fine, but not necessary. Now live events are too many, from FC Viktoria Plzen (w) 3 - 2 Pardubice (w) to Haukar Hafnarfjordur 0 - 0 UMF Vidir

Comment: Say the time is 18h00 GMT and I look at that list, is a match at 18:15 live? I'm confused. I thought live might be anything that has an entry in the time column but I see there is an entry for `Renate AC - Carrarese` which is listed for 20:00

Comment: @QHarr In my table view it's 21:00 o'clock, not 20:00. I think that's because I'am in Germany, which is in another time zone than the country the page is hostet. I can see 20:00 in the linked array list. I have done some research on arrays and can identify the following: ID. teams, league, score, start times, whether 1st half; half time break or 2nd half. I think the current playtime must be calculated.

Comment: Since there can also be simicolons within data fields, the direct approach via `Split()` as described by the OP does not work. A little care must be taken. Furthermore, the array rows are not always the same length. It can probably be solved via dictionaries and collections.

Comment: I believe the time depends of local time.
@Zwenn, I tried with IE and I can scrape the minutes. so I think that minutes arent'  the result of the calculation. The matches may have delays. 
How can I proceed with the extraction?

Comment: I'am sure the playtime is calculatet because I'am watchin `Bielefeld - Union Berlin` in this moment. I looked in the data of the linked JS which is filled with three arrays with all data you want. There are two starttimes. The second one is the starttime of the second half of a game. I have checked that. So you have 45 minutes from the first half. No matter how many additional time. If a game is in the first half, in the halftime break or in the second half you can see by the number after the second timestamp. 1 is first half, 2 is halftime break and 3 is second half. So you can calculate it.

Comment: If there is any other way, don't use IE any more. It is End Of Live and is supported by fewer and fewer sites. MS is currently in the process of actively preventing the use of IE and automatically switches to Edge when a page is called up in IE. Apart from that, IE is very slow. With xhr and the JS you picked out, you are much faster.

Comment: Ok, bye IE. Did you find the actual start time? Because if there are two times, the scheduled one and the actual one, then the calculation can be done. I honestly think a calculation like this is unreliable. Let's exclude the playtime, not a problem. The JS url is corrected or there is some other JS to parse?

Comment: Click https://www.goaloong.net/gf/data/bf_us.js Press Ctrl+a, Press Ctrl+c, click https://beautifier.io/ Select "Beautify JavaScript" in the upper left dropdown, click into textfield, press Ctrl+v Now you can see the JS in a better way. Every line with `A[x] = ...` is a match in the table of the page. The first timestamp is the start of the match, the second one is the starttime of the second half if it has started, the following number is 1,2 or 3 like I expained above. The both following numbers are the goals for each team.

Comment: Problem: If there is an extra line in the page table with *"kick of (team name)"* you have a datafield with simicolons like `';|2;|;|;;;;'` You can identify it by the pipes `|`. Thats the reason you can't simply split the whole JS by simicolon.

Comment: If there is a 0 istead of 1,2 or 3 for the part of the match, it has not started now.

Comment: In this moment I see A[3] = [1955571, 29, 2910, 51511, 'Central Coast Mariners', 'FC Macarthur', '2021-03-08 08:05:00', '2021-03-08 08:06:10'. Actual playtime is 37', I don't understand it, maybe it's calculated with the second time. 
Anyway what is the correct way to extract the single rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an overview of the datafields in array A. I have all 35 fields included, but 17 are unnown what they are for. Among other things, you should be able to see from the descriptions how you can calculate the correct playing time. For this you need the values 6 and 7 depending on the value 8. You can calculate with the given times no matter in which time zone a match takes place, because it is sufficient if all given times refer to the same time zone.

You can split the JS by `CrLf` into its rows:

```
splitAllJsRows = Split(.ResponseText, Chr(13))
```

[image]

Comment: My difficulty is to extract only the data I need and find the live event time. I need this data: ID-START TIME-LEAGUE-HOME-AWAY-SCORE-TIME.

row = Split(resp, Chr(13)) returns the same output

Comment: I have now really thought about whether I want to go further into what has been said so far. Since I have the impression that you lack the right approach, I will make the effort. I was a bit reluctant because I think there will be a lot to explain. It already starts with the fact that you have not understood the data so far. That's really not meant in a bad way. I don't know yet whether I will edit my answer today. But I'll get to work on further explanations.

Comment: Forgive me but I don't have the proper experience. Unfortunately it isn't a question of scraping a table, however I understand if you will decide not go further.

Comment: @Zimox No problem. I made my decision earlier. I have already written down a few things. But I won't finish it today because I have  to do also other things :-)

Comment: Thank you, I don't ask for the definitive code otherwise I don't learn

Comment: @ Zwenn what's the correct approach? I tried on excel with the TextToColumns method

Comment: @Zimox Did you have a solution for this in the meantime? I saw you ask another question for the same page. Sorry for my late response on this.

Comment: At the moment I haven't found a solution, regarding my other question, it's the same site but the page is formatted differently. For now no solution.

Comment: @Zimox Ok, I will look into this again this weekend.